# XOR operator in Javascript to check against value

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, xor

So, as far as I checked, there is no XOR operator for javascript.

There is tho the following -

`if( ( foo && !bar ) || ( !foo && bar ) ) {
  ...
}`

This is clear if foo and bar are boolean values. But can XOR be used to check against a different type of expression? For example if I would like to check a value against another value, that is -

`if (type === 'configuration' XOR type2 === 'setup') {
...
}`

Would it transform to something like -

`if ( (type === 'configuration' && type2 !== 'setup') || (type !== 'configuration' && type2 === 'setup' ) ) {
...
}`

Or would it look different?

This gives the following result -

`type = 'configuration' && type2 = 'setup': false
type = 'configurations' && type2 = 'setup': true
type = 'configuration' && type2 = 'setups': true
type = 'configurations' && type2 = 'setups': false`

Which matches the

`0 XOR 0 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0`

but I'm not sure if this will match for all cases.

Comment: Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: You could define `const xor = (a, b) => a && !b || !a && b` and then just use it `xor(type === 'configuration', type2 === 'setup')`. This is simple, reusable, maintainable and easy to read. Unlike bitwise operators and long logical expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest logical xor is:

```
a !== b
```

Or in your case:

```
if((type === 'configuration') !== (type2 === 'setup'))
```

There is also a bitwise xor (`^`) in javascript that works here too, as booleans are typecasted to 0 / 1 and vice versa:

```
if((type === "configuration") ^ (type2 === "setup"))
```

Comment: Hmm, so that's the same what I wrote, I guess? The ^ looks a great solution, since it's shorter and more clearer. Was it introduced in a specific ECMAscript version?

Comment: @Jogn It might be shorter, but I don't think it's clearer, unless you're in a team that you're sure already understands bitwise operators at a glance. Write code for *clear readability*, not for golfing.

Comment: @jogn I learned JS ~5/6 Years ago, and exists since then

Comment: For a great article on xor in Javascript see: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/xor.html